# R - best way to store zoo/data frame (stock portfolios) for subsequent analysis using iteration?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, merge, zoo

My script generates 10 3-stock portfolios from 5 total stocks and groups them together in a list. I would like to eventually analyze each portfolio (cumulative returns, variance, etc) and I am fairly certain the list is not the way to go.

I know how to generate separate data frames and run analysis without iteration, but that would be cumbersome, yet I am at a loss on how to structure this using iteration. I have considered creating an empty data frame, but am unsure how to structure it. Any suggestions/nudges are appreciated.

```
library(quantmod)

startDate = '2016-03-10'
endDate = '2017-03-10'

# Download 1-yr data 
stocks <- suppressWarnings(getSymbols(c("CIG", 
    "SO", "CNP", "NRG", "AES"),from=startDate, to=endDate))

# combine adjusted close data
prices <- merge.zoo(CIG[,6], SO[,6], CNP[,6], NRG[,6], AES[,6])

# Calculate Monthly returns
mo_end_pxs <- prices[endpoints(prices,on='months'),] # get monthly endpoints
monthly_ret <- ROC(mo_end_pxs,type='discrete') # calculate monthly returns
monthly_ret <- monthly_ret[!is.na(monthly_ret)] # remove NA from first month
colnames(monthly_ret) <- c("CIG", "SO", "CNP", "NRG", "AES")

# generate all possible portfolios 
poss_ports <- combn(stocks,3)
portfolios <- list() 
for (i in 1:ncol(poss_ports)){
    portfolios[[i]] <- monthly_ret[,poss_ports[,i]]
    }
```

Comment: I would think a list **is** the way to go. What do you plan to do next that would make working with a list difficult? This question is a bit too vague or possibly opinionated to really receive a clear answers. Perhaps you could edit this into a more clear programming question.

Comment: Not to be a party pooper, but data.frame is, under the hood, a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would totally leave it as a list.

You can access it simply: 
`portfolios[1]`

```
    [[1]]
                   CIG            SO          CNP
2016-04-29 -0.13274370 -0.0315097796  0.025334600
2016-05-31 -0.20021441 -0.0020678714  0.062807886
2016-06-30  0.48322121  0.0847492493  0.065246332
2016-07-29  0.25339362 -0.0024240452 -0.003333349
2016-08-31 -0.03610090 -0.0302915203 -0.049819374
2016-09-30 -0.02996270 -0.0005845002  0.033822879
2016-10-31  0.16602306  0.0052631794 -0.018510575
2016-11-30 -0.25496674 -0.0814869561  0.058405282
2016-12-30  0.05517647  0.0506193682  0.032690654
2017-01-31  0.24561404  0.0048790762  0.063717516
2017-02-28  0.16197183  0.0401680053  0.052930938
2017-03-07  0.12121212 -0.0082644235  0.024890190
```

Or you can query it by adding a specific query field after:

```
   portfolios[[1]][as.Date("2016-05-31")]

                  CIG           SO        CNP
2016-05-31 -0.2002144 -0.002067871 0.06280789
```

Or you can break each one into a data frame later to compare:

```
    y<-as.data.frame(portfolios[3])
str(y)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ CIG: num  -0.1327 -0.2002 0.4832 0.2534 -0.0361 ...
 $ SO : num  -0.03151 -0.00207 0.08475 -0.00242 -0.03029 ...
 $ AES: num  -0.04501 -0.00627 0.12534 -0.00154 -0.02267 ...
```

If you leave it in that list, you can ask it to iterate over the list with a `for` loop and save to data frames later, or access sums to columns directly, or compare the dates of each list element. 
Unless you have a specific future need, this seems like a reasonable way to maintain the data without a lot of overhead.

Comment: thanks very much, I had assumed the list wasn't the way to go since I was having difficulty adding new columns, but knowing this is the best way to proceed encouraged me to keep plugging away for solutions.